# javascript call function from php file! (using yii)

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to call a function in a .js file from the php page where I'm displaying it!

What I want to do is something like this:

.php file:

> ```
> ...
> function testFunc(){
>   return "2";
> }
> ...
> ```

now I want to call this function inside the .js file!

Thaks in advance for your help

Comment: It's slightly unclear what exactly you want to do. Please clarify by describing your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have tried?

Assuming the `testFunc` function is enclosed in proper script tags, 
your .js file can call it quite simply like this:

```
testFunc()
```

Ideally, you include the .js file after `testFunc` is declared.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs server side. JavaScript (assuming you are using it in a browser) runs client side. If you want to execute this PHP function from the client side and get the result without reloading the page, you have to do an ajax request, which may be beyond your skills.

Look into jQuery Ajax:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: -1 for assuming that this is beyond his or her skills. Think this is inappropriate.